# Pandas Auto Generate CSV

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datetime, pyodbc

I've to read data from a SQL server table every 5 minutes, resample the data & auto generate a .csv file everyday with the file name being the date. My code is follows:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import datetime
import time

conn = pyodbc.connect( driver='{SQL Server Native Client 11.0}',server='xyz', database='RW', Trusted_Connection='yes')
cursor = conn.cursor()

t_date=datetime.datetime.now().date()
today_date=pd.to_datetime(t_date)
tm_date = today_date + timedelta(days=1)
filename = str(t_date)+'.csv'
path = 'G:\\dump\\'

while 1:
    sql = '''SELECT * FROM weather_data WHERE TimeCol BETWEEN ? AND ? ORDER BY LOCALCOL ASC;'''
    df = pd.read_sql_query(sql, conn, index_col = 'Timecol', params =[today_date, tm_date])
    df1 = df.resample('15Min').mean()
    df1.index.names = ['Date Time']
    df1.to_csv(path+filename)
    time.sleep(300)
```

When I run the code for one day the .csv file is created, but the next day (after 00:00 Hrs) no new file is getting generated, unless I re-run the code.

Desired Behavior at 00:00 AM every day :

```
01-01-2020.csv
01-02-2020.csv
01-03-2020.csv
.
.
```

Kindly support what changes should I've to make so the .csv export will get automated everyday. Also, Please suggest if any fine tuning is required to make it robust. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the time date functions into the loop and the string definition out of the loop

```
sql = '''SELECT * FROM weather_data WHERE TimeCol BETWEEN ? AND ? ORDER BY LOCALCOL ASC;'''

while 1:
    t_date=datetime.datetime.now().date()
    today_date=pd.to_datetime(t_date)
    tm_date = today_date + timedelta(days=1)
    filename = str(t_date)+'.csv'
    df = pd.read_sql_query(sql, conn, index_col = 'Timecol', params =[today_date, tm_date])
    df1 = df.resample('15Min').mean()
    df1.index.names = ['Date Time']
    df1.to_csv(path+filename)
    time.sleep(300)
```